# Checking Enums Values - alternative to a switch case with 30 cases?

Tags: c#, if-statement, enums, switch-statement

I need to find if all conditions fit a certain criteria.

```
public class OfferServiceConditionDto
{

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public Parameter Parameter { get; set; }

    public Enums.Condition Condition { get; set; }

    public double? Value { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public long? OfferSubServiceId { get; set; }
}
```

Parameters has 5 cases:

> ```
> public enum Parameter : int
> {
>     Length,
>     Width
>     Height,
>     Area,
>     Volume
> }
> ```

Condition has 6 cases:

```
public enum Condition : int
{
    LessThan,
    LessThanOrEqualTo,
    Equals,
    GreaterThan,
    GreaterThanOrEqualTo,
    DoesNotEqual
}
```

IN my function I am given an element width height and length and I need to check against OfferServiceConditionDto  conditions, paremeters and  value.

So far I am only thinking switch cases or ifs but that's a whooping 30 checks.

Any better alternative for this?

Comment: Can you please add sample checks?

Comment: Do you have only one or multiple conditions? Using a dictionary for that might simplify your code

Comment: You can write a method with values and Condition enum as parameter and returns a boolean depending on the Condition enum, that's 6 conditions. Then use this method where you call your function. But we need details about how you call you function (a sample of your function would be great).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just extract some methods. By doing so, you can easily turn 30 (5 * 6) cases into
11 (5 + 6).

```
public static bool CheckCondition(double width, double height, double length, OfferServiceConditionDto dto) {
    switch (dto.Parameter) {
    case Parameter.Length:
        return CheckCondition(dto.Condition, length, dto.Value);
    case Parameter.Height:
        return CheckCondition(dto.Condition, height, dto.Value);
    // plus 3 more...
    }
    return false;
}

private static bool CheckCondition(Enums.Condition condition, double value1, double? value2) {
    if (value2 == null) {
        return true; // decide what to do if Value is null
    }
    switch (condition) {
    case Enums.Condition.LessThan:
        return value1 < value2.Value;
    case Enums.Condition.LessThanOrEqualTo:
        return value1 <= value2.Value;
    // plus 4 more...
    }
    return false;
}
```